# Change height of unordered list item in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list in my HTML:

**HTML:**

```
 <ul class="resp-tabs-list templatemo_testitab">
   <li>Testimonials</li>
   <li>Special Awards</li>
   <li>Recognitions</li>
   <li>New item</li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    color: #333333;
    background: #333333;
    font-size: 16px;
}
img { width: 100%; }

a {
    color: #ffffff; outline: 0;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cccccc;
}
a:active, a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
}

p {
    color: #333333;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
}
h1  {   font-size: 3em;
    color: #cccccc;
    background: #343537;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    float: left;
    text-shadow: 4px 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 1);
    margin: 5% 0% 0% 2%;;
    }

h2  { 
    font-size: 24px; 
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 0px;
    }
h3 { 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 2em;
    }

.clear  { clear: both; }
.content { display: none; height: auto; }
.homepage{ display: block; }
.portfolioshow  { display: block; }
/* .container   { position: absolute; } */

.templatemo_link ,.templatemo_linkservice,.templatemo_linkcontact { 
    font-size: 2em; color: #ffffff;
    width: 95%;
}

.templatemo_link1 { 
    font-size: 2em; color: #ffffff;
    padding-top:20%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_smalltitle { 
    float: left; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    color: #b5b5b5;
    margin: 10px 0px 30px 25px;
}

.templatemo_footer { 
    float: right; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #b5b5b5;
    margin: 30px 40px 20px 0px;
}

.templatemo_mainservice {
    background: #999933;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.templatemo_mainportfolio {
    background: #993333;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_maintesti {
    background: #339966;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_mainabout   {
    background: #cc9933;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_maincontact {
    background: #006699;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_insideportfolio  h2 { color: #ffffff; }
.templatemo_insideportfolio {
    background: #993333;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.templatemo_portfoliotext { 
    color: #ffffff;
    /*position: absolute; */
    width: 95%;
    padding: 30px;
}

.templatemo_portfolioback { 
    background: #666666;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_aboutback { 
    background: #666666;
    text-align: center;
}

.templatemo_graybg { 
    float: left; 
    background: #cccccc; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.templatemo_paddinggap  { padding: 30px; }
.templatemo_form { padding: 10px 0px; }
.templatemo_form input, .templatemo_form textarea { 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    border: 1px solid #999999; 
}

.templatemo_form textarea { 
    height: 150px;
}

.templatemo_form button {
    float: right;
    background: #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#templatemo_map { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
}

.templatemo_address { color: #757575; padding-top: 10px; }

/*------------------------------------------------------
    Gallery Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------*/
.gallery-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #666;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #666;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-item .content-gallery {
  text-align: center;
}
.gallery-item .content-gallery h3 {
  color: #b10021;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.gallery-item img {
  width: 100%;
}
.gallery-item .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}
.gallery-item .overlay a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.templatemo_frame { 
    float: left; overflow-x:hidden; margin-top: 30px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.templatemo_frame a {
    color: #06C;
}

.templatemo_frame a:hover {
    color: #C30;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

.resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab { float: left; width: 100%; }
.resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab li { padding: 0px; background: url(../images/templatemo_arrow_gap.png) no-repeat center right #cc9933; font-size: 24px; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; }
.resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab li.resp-tab-active{ background: url(../images/templatemo_arrow.png) no-repeat center right #cc9933; border: 0px; padding: 0px; color: #ffffff; }

.resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab { float: left; width: 100%; }
.resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab li { padding: 0px; background: url(../images/templatemo_arrow_gap.png) no-repeat center right #339966; font-size: 24px; text-align: center; font-weight: normal; }
.resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab li.resp-tab-active { background: url(../images/templatemo_testi_arrow.png) no-repeat center right #339966; border: 0px; padding: 0px; color: #ffffff;  }

.resp-vtabs .templatemo_aboutcontainer, .resp-vtabs .templatemo_testicontainer  {  background: none; border-radius: 0px; border: 0px; }
h2.resp-accordion   { color: #ffffff; }
.resp-tabs-list li  { color: #ffffff; }

.templatemo_testicontainer h2.resp-accordion {
 background: #339966 !important; }

.templatemo_aboutcontainer h2.resp-accordion {
 background: #cc9933 !important; }

/*----- Page Load ------*/

@media(min-width:320px) {
    .templatemo_leftgap { padding: 0px 10px; }
    .templatemo_rightgap_about  { padding: 0px 10px; }
    .templatemo_botgap  { margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px; }
    .templatemo_topgap, .templatemo_portfotopgap    { margin-top: 20px; }
    .templatemo_col37   { float: left; width: 100%; }
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_aboutcontainer, .resp-vtabs .templatemo_testicontainer  { width: 100%; }
    .templatemo_aboutlinkwrapper{ display: none; }
    .templatemo_aboutlinkwrapper1{  display: block; }
    .templatemo_frame   { padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px; }
    .templatemo_link { padding-top: 20%; }
    .logocontainer  { padding: 0px 15px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .templatemo_insideportfolio { padding-bottom: 30px; }
    .templatemo_link, .templatemo_linkservice, .templatemo_linkcontact  { padding: 50px 0px; }

}   
@media(min-width:320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    /*.container    { left: 15px; right: 15px; padding: 0px; }*/
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .templatemo_leftgap { padding: 0px 10px; }
    .templatemo_botgap  { margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px; }
    .templatemo_topgap  {   margin-top: 20px; }
    .templatemo_portfotopgap    { margin-top: 0px; } 
    .templatemo_link { padding-top: 20%; }
    /*.container { left: 50%; margin-left: -375px; right: 0px; }*/
    .logocontainer  { width: 750px; padding: 0px 15px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .templatemo_insideportfolio { height: 398px; }
    .templatemo_link, .templatemo_linkservice, .templatemo_linkcontact  { height: 189px; line-height: 189px; padding: 0px; }
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .templatemo_leftgap { padding: 0px 6px; }
    .templatemo_rightgap_about  { padding: 0px 6px 0px 2px; }
    .templatemo_botgap  { margin: 0px 0px 12px 0px; }
    .templatemo_topgap  {   margin-top: 0px; }
    .templatemo_portfotopgap    { margin-top: 0px; }
    .templatemo_bordergapborder { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
    .templatemo_graybg  {height: 397px; }
    .templatemo_col37   { float: left; width: 37.5%; }
    .templatemo_col50   { float: left; width: 50%; position: relative; }
    .templatemo_form { padding: 5px 0px; }
    .templatemo_form textarea { height: 120px; }
    .templatemo_address { font-size: 12px; }
    .templatemo_portfoliotext { width: 95%; padding: 15px ; font-size: 14px; }
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_aboutcontainer, .resp-vtabs .templatemo_testicontainer  { width: 75%; }
    .templatemo_leftgap_about   { padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px; }
    .templatemo_aboutlinkwrapper { width: 95.8%; float: left; background: #666666; text-align: center; display: block; }
    .templatemo_aboutlinkwrapper1 {  display: none; }
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_tab li,
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_testitab li{ padding: 0px;  margin-bottom: 12px; }
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab li, 
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab li.resp-tab-active, 
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab li, 
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab li.resp-tab-active   { line-height: 79px; height: 79px; }
    .templatemo_frame   { height: 337px; margin-right: 1px; padding: 0px 30px; }
    .templatemo_link { padding-top: 15%; }
    /*.container { left: 50%; margin-left: -485px; }*/
    .templatemo_link, .templatemo_linkservice, .templatemo_linkcontact { height: 124px; line-height: 124px; padding: 0px; }
    .logocontainer  { width: 970px; padding: 0px 15px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .templatemo_insideportfolio { height: 260px; }
}

@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .templatemo_leftgap { padding: 0px 8px; }
    .templatemo_rightgap_about  { padding: 0px 8px; }
    .templatemo_botgap  { margin: 0px 0px 16px 0px; }
    .templatemo_topgap  { margin-top: 0px; }
    .templatemo_portfotopgap    { margin-top: 0px; }
    .templatemo_bordergapborder { padding: 0px 16px; }
    .templatemo_graybg  { height: 466px; }
    .templatemo_col37   { float: left; width: 37.5%; position: relative; }
    .templatemo_col50   { float: left; width: 50%; position: relative; }
    .templatemo_form { padding: 10px 0px; }
    .templatemo_form textarea { height: 150px; }
    .templatemo_address { font-size: 14px; }
    .templatemo_portfoliotext { width: 95%; padding: 30px; font-size: 16px; }
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_aboutcontainer, .resp-vtabs .templatemo_testicontainer  { width: 75%; }
    .templatemo_leftgap_about   { padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; }
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab li, 
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_tab li.resp-tab-active, 
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab li, 
    .resp-vtabs ul.templatemo_testitab li.resp-tab-active { line-height: 93px; height: 93px; }
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_tab li, 
    .resp-vtabs .templatemo_testitab li { padding: 0px;  margin-bottom: 15px; }
    .templatemo_frame   { height: 806px; padding: 0px 30px; }
    .templatemo_link { height: 150px; line-height: 150px; padding: 0px; }
    /*.container { left: 50%; margin-left: -585px; }*/
    .logocontainer  { width: 1140px; padding: 0px 30px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .templatemo_insideportfolio { height: 316px; }
    .templatemo_leftgap_about .templatemo_link { height: 142px; line-height: 142px; padding: 0px; }
    .templatemo_linkservice, .templatemo_linkcontact { height: 145px; line-height: 145px; padding: 0px; }
}
```

These list items are shown in boxes in my file, and i want to change the height of these boxes, so where should i change my CSS code.

JSFiddle [[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xk43squ6/)]

Comment: Can we have the HTML ?

Comment: I'm sorry i missed a part of my code,this is the HTML code part that has unordered list <ul class="resp-tabs-list templatemo_testitab">
                <li>Testimonials</li>
                <li>Special Awards</li>
                <li>Recognitions</li>
                <li>New item</li>
            </ul>

Comment: Still cannot see your issue. Make a fiddle and send the link.

Comment: JSFiddle for his code http://jsfiddle.net/a843botj/2/

Comment: Please show just the relevant CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height` in this class `.resp-tabs-list li` like this

```
.resp-tabs-list li {
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
}
```

This will change the height of list items.

Working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a843botj/1/

Comment: this is the hole file can you help me please, thanks, http://www.megafileupload.com/Yv9/html.zip

Comment: @MilindaKasun What is your exact requirement? Can you please state that clearly?

Comment: I want to change the size of elements of unordered list, the list items are <li>Testimonials</li>
   <li>Special Awards</li>
   <li>Recognitions</li>
   <li>New item</li>